# What does Natalie Wood mean by "Well, stop the world" in the movie Rebel Without a Cause?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Here is a conversation from the movie [Rebel Without a Cause](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqGDruqXV5g&t=1m38s) 1:38.

> Jim: Hi. Hi. Wait a minute. Hi. I've seen you before.
>
> Judy: Well, stop the world.

What does Judy(Natalie Wood) mean by "Well, stop the world"?

Comment: She is being sarcastic. Such a momentous thing! Stop the world from spinning on its axis!

Comment: @TRomano That's a nice answer for me!

Comment: Yep, @TRomano, that sounds like an answer!

Comment: It's bordering on interpretation, so I'll leave it as a comment.  One might have said it was *faux* sarcasm.

Comment: @TRomano "*Such a momentous thing! Stop the world from spinning on its axis!*"
I don't understand this. Would you please elaborate?

Comment: @Makoto Kato: What specifically don't you understand?  She is referring to his statement that he has seen her before.

Comment: @TRomano What did she imply by *the world*?

Comment: @Makoto Kato: Planet Earth.

Comment: @TRomano You don't seem to understand my question.

Comment: It could also be referring to "The World"... the newspaper... As in "stop the presses"...

Answer (score 1):

Natalie Wood is using the expression

> Stop the world

sarcastically when Dean says he's seen her before, it has the same meaning as

> So what's, big deal
>   As if it's so momentous that the world should stop

she trying to play it cool and nonchalant with Dean whom she obviously likes.

It should not be confused with the 1961 musical

> [*Stop the World - I Want To Get Off*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_the_World_%E2%80%93_I_Want_to_Get_Off)

*Rebel Without A Cause* came out in 1955.

A similar phrase is

> stop the presses

which was used during the printed newspapers era when newspapers needed  to be updated due to breaking news.

Comment: What does James Dean say after she says *stop the world?* I can't quite make it out, something about being polite? Do you know, Peter?

Comment: What does NW mean by *you're a real yo-yo*? I wonder.

Comment: It means she thinks he could be up and down, emotionally, "I bet you're a real yo-yo", Dean after all is the dark brooding type, in contrast to her friends in the car who are very happy-go-lucky.